# Does anyone know why the output is "Obama" not "Clinton"?

Tags: javascript, this

```
function setName(obj){
    obj.name = "Obama";
    obj = {name:"Clinton"};
}
var president = {name:"Bush"};
setName(president);
console.log(president.name);
```

When I change “obj.name = "Obama";” to “this.name = "Obama";”

```
function setName(obj){
    this.name = "Obama";
    obj = {name:"Clinton"};
}
var president = {name:"Bush"};
setName(president);
console.log(president.name);
```

The output becomes "Bush".

Comment: What do you expect `this` to represent?

Comment: Did you expect `this` and `obj` to refer to the same object? Why?

Comment: @Ryan I expect "this" to represent "obj"

Comment: If you do `obj.setName()`, then `this` is the `obj`. But you would have to add the `setName` function to the object to be able to do this.

Comment: `var obj = { name: "Obama", setName: function() { console.log(this) }}; obj.setName()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added some comments to help understand what is happening.

```
function setName(obj){

    // change obj's name property to Obama
    obj.name = "Obama";

    // change the reference to obj to a new object inside setName.
    // this does not affect the original object being passed in.
    obj = {name:"Clinton"};
}
var president = {name:"Bush"};
setName(president);
console.log(president.name);


function setName2(obj){

    // change this's name property to Obama. this is set to window/global, not obj.
    this.name = "Obama";

    // change the reference to obj to a new object inside setName.
    // this does not affect the original object being passed in.
    obj = {name:"Clinton"};
}
var president2 = {name:"Bush"};
setName2(president2);
console.log(president2.name);
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, this is a good explanation of the problem +1

Answer (score 4):

`this` is not the `obj`.
You can try this to understand:

```
function setName(obj){
  console.log(this.name);
}
```

It will not give you `obj`.
Well if you really think bad about using the `obj` word try this:

```
function setName(obj){
  setName.arguments[0].name = "Obama";
  obj = {name:"Clinton"}; // I don't touch this.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the local variable `obj`, the scope of which is inside the function. It is no more than a reference to the object. Thus the update `obj = { name: "Clinton" };` does not affect any state outside the function.

But changing the object's name affects its contents. This is why you are getting "Obama".

`this.name = "Obama"` has no relevant effect on `president`, since `this` is not the `president`.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying an object reference and not the object itself.

This line is modifying the initial object.  Obj is currently pointing to the initial object which is the same as the Object that president is pointing to.

```
obj.name = "Obama";
```

The next line assigns the variable to a new object reference.  It no longer refers to the initial object.  The variable president is still pointing at the initial object and thus you get "Obama" and not "Bush"

```
obj = {name:"Clinton"};
```

Answer (score 0):

**In the first case:**

When invoking setName with the president object, it first sets the name of the object to Obama. Since you passed an object as a parameter, all properties that change, will be changed to the initial object as well. When overriding the entire object `obj = {name:"Clinton"};`, you lose the reference and you don't return the object, so nothing happens with it. The name is set to Obama in the first step and it will stay Obama.

**In the second case:**

Same as above and the this-context is related to the setName scope. You're not using setName as an Object or it's not part of an Object, so there's not really a usable this-context here. You could attach one by using call:

```
setName.call(president, null);
```

The first argument is the this-context and the other arguments are the parameters of the method. However, I would not recommend doing that for this scenario.

**setName used on an Object:**

To use a method setName on an object, you could do this for example:

```
function President(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
President.prototype.setName = function(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

var president = new President('Clinton');
president.setName('Obama');
```

Since you're using `new`, you create a new this-context and set the name property to Clinton while creating the Object.

Also, this could work:

```
function President(name) {
  var presidentName = name;

  return {
    getName: function() {
      return presidentName;
    },
    setName: function(name) {
      presidentName = name;
    }
  };
}
```